# Mismatched types float64 and int

Tags: arrays, go

I'm trying to create random grades and adding them to a `test_scores` array. Then calculate the average.

This program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    i := 0
    var test_scores [5]float64
    for i < len(test_scores) {
        test_scores[i] = rand.Float64()
        i++
    }
    fmt.Println(test_scores)

    var total float64 = 0
    i = 0
    for i < len(test_scores) {
        total += test_scores[i]
        i++
    }
    fmt.Println(total)
    fmt.Println(total / len(test_scores))
}
```

produces:

```
main.go:24: invalid operation: total / 5 (mismatched types float64 and int)
```

This one works fine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    i := 0
    var test_scores [5]float64
    for i < len(test_scores) {
        test_scores[i] = rand.Float64()
        i++
    }
    fmt.Println(test_scores)

    var total float64 = 0
    i = 0
    for i < len(test_scores) {
        total += test_scores[i]
        i++
    }
    fmt.Println(total)
    fmt.Println(total / 5)
}
```

---

The only difference being that in the final line, I'm using a fixed `5` and on the non-working one, I'm using the `len(test_scores)` call.

[Len](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) returns an integer as well, so what's up?

Comment: You should usually use slices instead of arrays.

Comment: "This program crashes" is unhelpful. When asking questions please include more information. [I've edit the error message into your question.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `5` directly in the source-code that's called a constant. Same goes for writing `true`. The only difference is that the former is an *untyped* constant and the latter a *typed* constant.

The difference lies in that there's no ambiguity about what type `true` should have – it'll always be `bool` but in the case of `5` that's not so obvious and depends on the context.

The Go compiler will figure out what type to give the constant on compilation. The details of this are described in [Go's language specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants).

Edit:

I realized that there's a mistake in my answer: `true` is in fact also untyped according to the spec because it may be utilized anywhere where a type deriving from `bool` is expected. That means:

```
type MyBool bool

func DoNothing(b MyBool) {}

DoNothing(true) // true is coerced to MyBool
```

The answer is still valid, though. The distinction between typed and untyped constants holds.

Comment: Another good source of information about constants is [The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants).

Answer (score 5):

`float64` and `int` are different types, but conversions are allowed under specific circumstances. (http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

Your literal `5` in the code is an untyped constant (http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants), and the proper type is determined by the expression during compilation.

Simply use `float64(len(test_scores))`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm wondering why `5` works, and `len(test_scores)` doesn't since `len()` returns an integer and `5` -is-  an integer.

Comment: Added reference to Go constants. Read through the spec. It's very approachable, and will answer all these details.

Answer (score -1):

This lines

```
fmt.Printf("%T\n", total)
fmt.Printf("%T\n", 5)
fmt.Printf("%T\n", 5.0)
fmt.Printf("%T\n", len(test_scores))
```

prints

```
float64
int
float64
int
```

Maybe compiler perceives 5 as 5.0.. Anyway you should use conversion to float64.

Comment: No, the compiler perceives them as untyped constants, it just happens to be converting them to a native `int` and `float64` when evaluated in `fmt.Printf()`